# Need to show the div before the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show this codepen html code before loading the page and then after some user's input the page loads.

Basically I am trying to show the below codepen div on page load which will ask the user to select something and then upon successful selection the page loads with the remaining contents. But I need a little help. I also tried window.load() in javascript but no result.

https://codepen.io/leenalavanya/pen/XdrOzg?editors=1100

```js
function g(a, n) {
  var divs = "";
  for (var s = 0; s < 50; s++) {
    divs += '<div class="div ball"  id="' + getRandom() + '"></div>';
  }
  document.getElementById(a).innerHTML += divs;
}
g('h1');
g('h3');

function f(x, n, a) {
  var t = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (t < 50) {
      x.style.bottom = (46 * t * n - t * t) + 20 + 'px';
      x.style.height = 10 - t / 4.6 + 'px';
      x.style.width = 10 - t / 4.6 + 'px';
      if (t > 15) {
        x.style.left = (a * t + 150) + 'px';
        x.style.bottom = (46 * t * n * n - t * t) + 20 + 'px';
      }
      t += 1.3
    }
  }, 50)
}

function Launch() {
  if ($('.revealleft,.revealright').hasClass('revealed')) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName('div')[i];
      var a = parseInt(x.id);
      x.style.left = '150px';
      f(x, 1 + ((Math.random() * 5) + 1) / 100, a)
    }
  }
}

function getRandom() {
  return Math.random() * 10 - 5
}
```

```css
html,body{background:#e6e6e6;width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}
.reveal{width:600px;height:350px;box-shadow:0 0 30px -5px grey;background:#fff;margin:calc(50vh - 175px) auto;max-width:96%;position:relative;overflow:hidden}
.revealleft,.revealright{width:50%;background:#dc143c;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0;transition:all 1s}
.revealright{left:50%}
.revealleft.revealed{left:-50%}
.revealright.revealed{left:100%}
.reveal button{opacity:.99;margin:15px;padding:8px 15px;background:#dc143c;border:2px solid #fff;border-radius:6px;color:#fff;cursor:pointer;position:absolute}
.reveal button:hover{background:#fff;color:#dc143c;outline:0;border-color:#dc143c}
.reveal button:focus{outline:0}
h1{font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;font-size:4vw;margin:50px 30px 35px;text-align:center;color:#dc143c}
p{margin:0 30px;font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;color:grey;font-size:.8em;line-height:1.7em}
img{width:160px;float:right;margin:5px 0 5px 20px}
.ball{width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:100%;position:absolute;bottom:20px;left:50%;background:#dc143c}
#h1,#h3{position:absolute;bottom:-15px;width:300px;height:100%;z-index:100;pointer-events:none;-webkit-transform-origin:center bottom}
```

```html
<div id="h1" style="left:-150px;-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg)">
</div>
<div id="h3" style="right:-140px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg)"></div>
<div class="reveal">
  <div class="revealleft"></div>
  <div class="revealright"></div>
  <button onclick="$('.revealleft,.revealright').toggleClass('revealed');Launch()">Reveal</button>
  <h1>A SURPRISE!</h1>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.fndvisions.org/img/cutecat.jpg"></img>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis augue luctus, auctor eros at, commodo purus. Suspendisse potenti. Ut vel blandit nibh. Mauris luctus mollis turpis, at euismod
    quam fermentum iaculis. Donec non lectus vel purus porta ornare et vitae est. Sed porta luctus purus, at hendrerit lorem congue nec.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you googled for how to hide/show elements on a web page?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Thanks... I just realized that we should first hide the element and then display on page load... Sorry that I forgot this silly mistake.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty After using the display :none by default and then enabling it isn't working can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing this:

1- Let the page and scrips load normally.

2- Get User inputs with proper UI (custom HTML forms or prompt)
You can show the input form after the page load

3- Manipulate the DOM using javascript according to the user's inputs.
You can add or manipulate all elements after getting the inputs of the user.